# Python .toml and .cfg nonsense?

Tags: python, package, configuration-files, toml

I am having a hard time configure proper cfg and toml files....
I just want to understand these, I am coming from a Java background, and nothing clear from my researches.

1. Why namespaces are so bad ? Simple python project would take the first folder / package as a name... if I call it SQLAlchemy it will override the real SQLAlchemy on pip as a base name...
2. What is the use of .cfg file ? If I have a bunch of packages it should be a .cfg in each, not a global one as it retains 'version' for only one package, and have a 'package dir search and find' option...
3. .cfg is useless look, i have this project :

```
    ZeProject
    |
    | -- src
    |    | - Whatever
    |       | - Package1
    |       |   | - somefiles.py
    |       | - Package2
    |       |   | - somefiles.py
```

So this should be 2 modules right ? So why do I have only 1 cfg file for a version ?
While I have a toml for the project version ?
Neither the namespace is taken in consideration...

Let's see, this is my .toml :

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "stfulama"
version = "4"
```

and this is my .cfg :

```
[metadata]
version = 666

[options]
package-dir = 
    = src
namespace_packages = wow

[options.packages.find]
where = youwant
```

It installs perfectly with pip install, with the project name 'stfulama', and version 4... nothing of the .cfg is taken in consideration, from the stupid stuff I wrote, I can import in an other project : import from whatever.package1 or whatever.package2

Can anyone explain me the use of these ? And why there is no namespace as se ? And why python library (pip) can be override with a simple package name ? I am so confused

Answer (score 1):

> Why namespaces are so bad ?

Package namespacing is a community decision with advantages and drawbacks. The python community has largely fallen on the side of not doing it, in part for social reasons and in part for technological reasons: the language historically did not support "namespace packages" and they were not easy to implement, and as they were opt-in easy to screw up. So only specific multi-project organisations would use namespaces in order to put all their stuff together.

[PEP 420](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/) improved on that, but the habit remains, and as does the idea of "useless namespaces".

It's not like calling your package org.sqlalchemy prevents somebody else from calling *their* package org.sqlalchemy. The package *registry* might do so, but the same will happen with a bare `sqlalchemy`.

> What is the use of .cfg file ?

`setup.cfg` is used to perform declarative configuration of `setuptools`. Literally the second hit on google yields https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html

It predates pyproject.toml, and as a result there are redundancies between the two, mostly in that the `[metadata]` table of `setup.cfg` and the [`[project]`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/) table of `pyproject.toml` are both declarative means of expressing [package metadata](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/core-metadata/).

> So this should be 2 modules right ?

It's one package.

> So why do I have only 1 cfg file for a version ?

Because it's one package.

> It installs perfectly with pip install, with the project name 'stfulama', and version 4... nothing of the .cfg is taken in consideration

Try removing the setup.cfg and see what happens.

> And why python library (pip) can be override with a simple package name ?

I have no idea what that means. And pip is not "python library", whatever that means as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,

Not preventing someone to use an organisation name, right, but preventing myself to use an already used name as a package, that may already being installed on the poduction side.

Tho from the python docs I have read, each folder is a 'package' (with an init.py inside, which I forgot to mention) so why are you saying this is only one package ?

I removed the .cfg and nothing happened, version of the toml, installed with te toml

And sorry to call pip a python library, I meant official package manager / installer of course

Comment: "Tho from the python docs I have read, each folder is a 'package' (with an init.py inside, which I forgot to mention)" the term is quite overloaded, I was talking about package in a packaging sense, where it's about equivalent to a project.

Comment: "I removed the .cfg and nothing happened, version of the toml, installed with te toml" sounds unlikely. If I remove the setup.cfg of a setuptools-based project, it stops packaging (sdist and wheel stop building), unless the setup.cfg is not actually used because there's a setup.py with all the same information. Because the src layout is not the normal setuptools layout.